What is the role of time compensation in TwinCAT, and how does it affect synchronization between master and slave axes?
I’m trying to understand how time compensation works in TwinCAT, as mentioned in the Beckhoff documentation.
https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tf50x0_tc3_nc_ptp/10650596235.html&id=
We have a PTO axis (EL2522 module) connected to a DAQ to match the signal with position data. This PTO axis acts as the master for multiple physical slave axes in our device.
During cam movement, we observed that the slaves are not in the expected position according to the cam table at any given time. This mismatch is consistent, and we suspect it may be related to time synchronization or compensation between the master and slave axes.
Could someone explain how time compensation in TwinCAT works and how it affects the synchronization between the master and slave axes during camming operations? Could it be the cause of the observed position mismatch?
